# Joomla extension module EU e-Privacy Directive is not clearing the HTTP cookies

Tags: php, joomla2.5, session-cookies, joomla-extensions

I am using EU e-Privacy Directive Plugin and Module. When I remove cookies using the module it is not working. I can still see some cookies. I Think the module isn't clearing all the HTTP Cookies. Why?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask the developer (that's me)

You may be seeing cookies from subdomains, or your /administrator login.  The plugin can't do anything about these because they already exist and are restricted by the javascript same-origin policy.

You may also be seeing cookies previously set by 3rd parties.  Again, the plugin is restricted by the javascript same-origin policy.  If a 3rd party cookie already exists, the plugin can't do anything about it.

If you have the plugin configured correctly (PHP 5.3 + PHP Reflection + proper group/ACL assignment to 3rd-party-cookie plugins and modules), the plugin can effectively prevent them until a user allows them.  Once allowed though a 3rd party cookie can't be removed by the plugin because of the javascript same-origin policy.